# How can I join these two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have manually coded to display ship Fiscal Week Numbers and breaked into month

```
select `Ship Fiscal Week Number`,
    CASE
    WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number` <=5 THEN "January"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 9 THEN "Feburary"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number` <=13 THEN "March"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 18 THEN "April"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 22 THEN "May"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 26 THEN "June"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 31 THEN "July"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 35 THEN "August"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 39 THEN "September"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 44 THEN "October"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 48 THEN "November"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 52 THEN "December"
    else "Nothing"
    END AS `Ship Fiscal Period Number`
```

Then I want to join this with other table which displays data like this :

```
  select  Product,
  Ship Fiscal Week Number,
  Ship Fiscal Year Number,
  Order  Group,
  Amount,
  Invoices,
  Order_Quantity
  from table 2
```

So how can I club this to display  o/p like this :

```
Product A| January| Eyemakeup
```

Where I want instead of ship fiscal week number it shall show me which month is that ship fiscal week # comes under.

thanks.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, and what column equates to "Eyemakeup", but if the columns listed in the second query is available in one table then you can do this:

```
 select  Product,
    CASE
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number` <=5 THEN "January"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 9 THEN "Feburary"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number` <=13 THEN "March"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 18 THEN "April"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 22 THEN "May"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 26 THEN "June"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 31 THEN "July"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 35 THEN "August"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 39 THEN "September"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 44 THEN "October"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 48 THEN "November"
     WHEN Ship Fiscal Week Number`<= 52 THEN "December"
    else "Nothing"
    END AS `Ship Fiscal Month`
  from table 2
```

Comment: Format your code properly.  People can't read those.  You're just wasting your time.

Comment: @DennisLi  My first table looks like this :                                                                     Table 1:

Comment: Hi @S.Y.K.J I don't see the Table 1 information. 

Does the query I provided work with your data? You can keep your case statement, and if the ship fiscal week number is in that table 2, then you just use the case statement against that actual column name. But it doesn't appear you are providing actual column names, which would be helpful.